# "Pure virtual variable" OR: how to force derived class to init a static member variable?

Tags: c++, class, static, virtual, member

I have a singleton class Light and derived types SpecialLight and NormalLight. Both derived classes *need* to initialize the static member variable "Colors" with some specific content, while the base class should remain non-instantiable. How can I make my base class (Light) not instantiable (pure virtual), while forcing the subclasses to initialize the static var "Colors"?

```
class Light
{
    private:
        static const Color Colors[]; // <-- "pure virtual" would be nice here
}

class SpecialLight:Light
{
    private:
        static const Color Colors[] = { Color("yellow"), Color("blue"), Color("magenta") };
}
```

Unfortunately there are no pure virtual variables in C++, but this would be exactly what I need here. So how can I move arount this problem?

**EDIT**: The derived classes are singletons as well.

**EDIT2**: Apparently this needs some more explanation.

**Q**: Why is the lamp and the subclasses supposed to be a singleton?
**A**: This is code for a microcontroller in a lamp which controls the brightness of specific LEDs. However, this code is used in multiple different lamps which have different LEDs. My idea was to specify a light object which includes all functionality that goes into the control of these LEDs. But because the lamps are different (different pin mappings etc.) I need to have different light classes which each define the pin mapping, frequency etc. differently. The idea is to only instantiate only ONE of these light classes which becomes the singleton class through which all further operations run. The base class just implements the functionality for an unified interface and will never be instantiated.

**Q**: Why does the base class need to be purely virtual?
**A**: Because it is never supposed to be instantiated because it lacks the information about pin mapping etc.. It is not fully functionable in that sense. To prevent this I would like to get an error if some function accidentaly tries to instantiate it.

**Q**: Why don't you make the class abstract e.g. by deleting the constructor?
**A**: I need an implementation of the constructor in the base class as all lights will need the same "init" functionality (initialising the LED timer module), hence I can't declare it purely virtual.

Comment: You cant have virtual static things since virtual is used to take a decision on the type of an object and static are per class not per object

Comment: make it a pure virtual method that returns the array. The array that is returned can be a static member in the subclasses

Comment: Yes I thought about making the accessor to Color a virtual function if there's no other way around it. @molbdnilo I added the note that the derived classes shall be singletons as well.

Comment: as a side note - having light as a singleton - and then inheriting it - and then making that also a singleton, it's a very strange design. You're saying "There can be only one light .... except for the fact that I've got at least 2"  I suspect it's cleaner to say "here's what a light is like" and then in another class "There's only one light, and this is it"

Comment: According to your description, you want all these to be true at the same time: "there can be no Light", "there can be exactly one Light", and "there can be exactly as many Lights as there are derived classes". This is contradictory. (When you retrieve the `Light` singleton instance, which object is that? The `NormalLight` or the `SpecialLight`?)

Comment: May use CRTP with trait class and common virtual base

Comment: You can't have virtual variables, or virtual static anything. The static variable in the subclass is a *completely unrelated variable* to the one in the base class.

Comment: You're mixing concepts in a way that doesn't work.  From your description, `Light` cannot be a singleton, and its member cannot be static. You need to (1) have a non-static member (e.g. a `std::vector<Color>`) in `Light`. (2) Provide `Light` a constructor that accepts a set of `Color`s (e.g. a `vector<Color>` or a `initializer_list<Color>` as an argument, and initialises the member. Optionally, that constructor can be `protected`. (3) Have derived classes define a constructor that calls the base class constructor.    (4)  Force the derived classes to each be singletons, and manage accordingly.

Comment: I have clarified certain things up in EDIT2

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I have been thinking and I would go with your solution. Would you care to put it in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: "But because the lamps are different (different pin mappings etc.) I need to have different light classes which each define the pin mapping, frequency etc. differently". Why do you need to make all of these differences expressed at the class level? Why not at the object/value level? We don't make 5 and 42 objects of different types, there's no reason to, the difference between 5 and 42 is at the value level.

Comment: If you do need a distinction at the type level for some reason, then you might be better off with class templates, where the Light template is parameterised by colours, pin mapping and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to express the following invariant:

> Any class derived from `Light` is known to have a `const static` member `Colors` of type `Color[]`.

Now you're essentially correct that *virtual* associates stuff to the runtime type of an object, and if you were able to have this "stuff" include not only methods but arbitrary data then you'd be able to store this `Colors` member inside the vtable of each class derived from `Light`.

If this is the sort of approach you want to take, then it implies that any time you want to access `Colors` you have on hand an instance of a derived class.  If that's your use case, then you can just use a virtual method, like so:

```
class Light
{
  public:

    virtual std::vector<Color> & getColors() = 0;
};

class NormalLight : public Light
{
  private:

    static std::vector<Color> _colors;

  public:

    std::vector<Color> & getColors() final
    {
      return _colors;
    }
}
```

However, this is more limited that what you'd get from a true static member.

If there really is only ever going to be one instance of any class derived from `Light`, you could instead have `Light` own a static member that its derived classes inherit, and which they initialize from their constructors.  Then when the constructor for whatever kind of light you have is called, the static member will be initialized.

```
class Light
{
  public:

    static Light * instance;

    static std::vector<Color> Colors;

    Light * getInstance()
    {
      assert(instance != nullptr);
      return instance;
    }

    void createInstance(const std::string & type);

};

class NormalLight : public Light
{
  public:

    NormalLight()
    {
      Colors = { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
    }      
};

class SpecialLight : public Light
{
  public:

    SpecialLight()
    {
      Colors = { MAROON, MINT, MIDNIGHT };
    }      
};

// ...

static Light * Light::instance = nullptr;

static std::vector<Color> Light::Colors;

void Light::createInstance(const std::string & type)
{
  assert(instance == nullptr);

  if(type == "Normal")
  {
    Light::instance = new NormalLight();
  }
  else 
  {
    Light::instance = new SpecialLight();
  }
}
```

This is missing `Light::Colors` being const, but that seems inherently necessary if we only determine its value at runtime after determining whether whether we are a normal or a special light.

A final approach would be to use templates.  This gets us closer to the idea of "any type of this form has a member called such-and-such."

In particular, you can just give both `NormalLight` and `SpecialLight` their own `const static` members called `Color`, and then use the magic of templates to access the member with that *name*.  Here's an example:

```
struct ILight
{
  void setColor(Color);
};

template<class T>
class Light : public ILight
{
  private:

    Color myColor;
  
  public:
  
  void setColor(Color newColor)
  { 
    for(Color color : T::Colors)
    {
      if(color == newColor)
      {
        myColor = newColor;
        return;
      }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Color not allowed");
  }
  
  Color getColor() { return myColor; }
};


struct NormalLight : public Light<NormalLight>
{
  const static Color Colors[];
};


struct SpecialLight : public Light<NormalLight>
{
  const static Color Colors[];
};

// ...

const Color NormalLight::Colors[] = { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
const Color SpecialLight::Colors[] = { MAROON, MINT, MIDNIGHT };
```

I'm honestly not sure I recommend any of these approaches; in fact, I don't really recommend the use of singletons at all.  That said, I hope this clears up some of the issues involved and helps you make your own decisions about the tradeoffs.

Comment: That was really helpful and it cleared things up a lot, thank you!